# Thread safe PQconn object

Tags: c++, multithreading, postgresql, libpq

I want to access a PostgreSQL table across a number of threads. How can I safeguard PQconn* object while multithreading? Does [libpq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq.html) library offer any method for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single connection to PostgreSQL does not support simultaneous queries. When a query is active, it's not possible to reuse its `PGconn` structure for anything else, with the exception of `PQcancel()` that may be called from another thread or a signal handler.

This comes from the design of the client-server protocol, not libpq itself.

To implement concurrent queries within multiple threads, each thread must have its own connection and its own corresponding non-shared `PGconn` structure.

Comment: Even if i have a separate PGconn for each thread, all will access a single shared table at the same time. Hence the concurrent querying will produce undesirable results, isn't it? In that case how can i manage shared table across threads?

Comment: It depends on the kind of access. If it's read-only, no problem. If not, [MVCC rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html) apply, you have to choose an isolation level that best fits your needs and deal with the conflicts that the db engine itself cannot solve.